# Count the CPP inline code lines via GNU Compiler

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, inline, gnu

Is it possible to count the C++ inline code lines that moved into your own binary, and are from included LGPL libaries?

Comment: As the inlining depends on compiler heuristic, except if the compiler provides the facility, probably not. Especially since these can be optimized away.

Comment: There is probably no easy way. I think it should be possible with libclang.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to do it through the GNU Compiler itself. However, writing your own script to count lines is very easy. Or, if you'd like, you can use an external counter like [CLOC](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/) to count the lines for you.